# Fokker-Planck Partition function

Tags: statistical-mechanics, path-integral, partition-function, stochastic-processes

Does a [multidimensional Fokker-Planck equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation#Higher_dimensions) always have a *stationary* solution? Is it posisble to write this solution in a partition-function-liek for to enable the analysis using the methods of statistical physics?

More specifically, I am talking about an equation of type:
$$
\frac{\partial P(\mathbf{x},t)}{\partial t} =
-\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left[\mu_i(\mathbf{x})P(\mathbf{x},t)\right] +
\sum_{i,j=1}^N\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}\left[D_{ij}(\mathbf{x})P(\mathbf{x},t)\right]
$$
(with time-independent coefficients). In the case where $$
\mu_i(\mathbf{x})=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}U(\mathbf{x}),$$
and
$$
D_{ij}=\delta_{i,j}D
$$
this equation has a Boltzmann-like stationary solution
$$
P_0(\mathbf{x}) \propto e^{-\frac{U(\mathbf{x})}{D}}.
$$
The stationary solution is also easy to find in one-dimensional case. I am looking for a general expression in order to analyze a strongly multi-dimensional case: $N\rightarrow + \infty$.

The particular motivation is studying a phase transition between *niche* and *neutral* regimes for bacterial communities, described by stochastic [Lotka-Volterra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations) equations, as in [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4246938/).